# Use one submit button to enter various pages in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, input, validating

I want to enter different rooms with on button. How is this possible in Javascript. For example, there are three rooms, "Kitchen, toilet and bedroom". How can I use JS to enter any of these rooms depending on my choice. so if i enter "kitchen" in the input box its gonna take me to kitchen.php, if I enter toilet...the same button is going to take me to toilet.php etc.

This is the HTML input,

```
<form method="post">
<input style=""name="Text1" type="text"><br>
<input name="move" style="height: 23px" type="submit" value="Move">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm afraid we need a bit more information than that. Maybe provide details as to where the form submits, what happens when it submits, how you determine a room, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a select field [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/Nfwhg/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<head> 
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> 
<title>Untitled 1</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function submitForm() {
    var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
    var mytext = document.getElementById('room');
    myroom = mytext.value.toLowerCase();
    if (myroom == 'kitchen') {
        myform.action = 'kitchen.php';
        myform.submit();
    } else if (myroom == 'toilet') {
        myform.action = 'toilet.php';
        myform.submit();
    } else if (myroom == 'bedroom') {
        myform.action = 'bedroom.php';
        myform.submit();
    } else return false;
}

window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('move').onclick = submitForm;
}
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" id="room" name="room" />
     <button id="move" name="move" style="height: 23px">Move</button> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

On the php side create three files to test to see if this works, toilet.php, kitchen.php, and bedroom.php with the following code in all three files.  make sure the file names are lower cased:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['room'];
?>
```

Basically, based on the option that is selected, the JavaScript would change the form's action url and submit.  If none is selected it'll return false and not submit.  The submitForm function is attached to the move button with an onclick event.

Comment: Ok...How can I JS the selection tag...to go to the three seperate rooms...like kitchen.php, toilet.php etc

Comment: @Kelvin also, please up vote/accept answers that solves your questions.  It'll motivate people to want to help you in the future on StackOverflow.

Comment: @kjy112 I really don't know. even when I used an entire new webpage: see this... http://www.thirdworld.vacau.com/game/hope.php It still doesn't work. Plus, I need it to be an input(text) not a select field. Can you help me please even if its in php. I'm handing in my work tomorrow :)

Comment: @Kelvin i added window.onload to wrap onclick attachment to the move button.  take a look at the new code i changed a few things to make it easier to understand for u

Comment: Thank You so much. Now, the last but not the least. Its about sessions. Please check it here, please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211694/sessions-how-can-i-display-a-the-users-row